# vagrant up command times out after "SSH auth method: private key" line

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, vagrantfile

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on in VirtualBox on Windows 8.1 operating system.

I boot my Virtual box with Ubuntu 16.04 and inside it, when I am trying to run `vagrant up`, it freezes at `default: ssh auth method: private key` line and finally times out after 600 seconds (which I set into Vagrantfile).

> Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
>   Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
>   the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period. If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors are usually good hints as to what may be wrong. If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes. Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
>   as well. If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

I am running `vagrant up` command from its location.

`$ /var/www/yrc-2017$ vagrant up`

**My Vagrantfile looks like this:**

```
if Gem::Version.new(Vagrant::VERSION) < Gem::Version.new("1.5.0")
    puts "ERROR: Outdated version of Vagrant"
    puts "  Chassis requires Vagrant 1.5.0+ "
    puts
    exit 1
end

if not File.exist?(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "puppet", "modules", "apt", ".git"))
    puts "NOTICE: Submodules not found, updating for you"

    if not system("git submodule update --init", :chdir => File.dirname(__FILE__))
        puts "WARNING: Submodules may be missing, and could not automatically\ndownload them for you."
    end

    # Extra new line, please!
    puts
end

require_relative "puppet/chassis.rb"
CONF = Chassis.config

Chassis.install_extensions(CONF)

base_path = Pathname.new( File.dirname( __FILE__ ) )
module_paths = [ base_path.to_s + "/puppet/modules" ]
module_paths.concat Dir.glob( base_path.to_s + "/extensions/*/modules" )

module_paths.map! do |path|
    pathname = Pathname.new(path)
    pathname.relative_path_from(base_path).to_s
end

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    # Set up potential providers.
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        # Use linked clones to preserve disk space.
        vb.linked_clone = true if Vagrant::VERSION =~ /^1.8/
    end

    config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"

    # Adding boot timeout
    config.vm.boot_timeout = 600

    # Enable SSH forwarding
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true

    # Disable updating of Virtual Box Guest Additions for faster provisioning.
    if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-vbguest")
        config.vbguest.auto_update = false
    end

    # Having access would be nice.
    if CONF['ip'] == "dhcp"
        config.vm.network :private_network, type: "dhcp", hostsupdater: "skip"
    else
        config.vm.network :private_network, ip: CONF['ip'], hostsupdater: "skip"
    end
    config.vm.hostname = CONF['hosts'][0]
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2222, host_ip: "127.0.0.1", id: 'ssh'

    preprovision_args = [
        CONF['apt_mirror'].to_s,
        CONF['database']['has_custom_prefix'] ? "" : "check_prefix"
    ]
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "puppet/preprovision.sh", :args => preprovision_args

    config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
        puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
        puppet.manifest_file  = "development.pp"

        module_paths.map! { |rel_path| "/vagrant/" + rel_path }
        puppet.options = "--modulepath " +  module_paths.join( ':' ).inspect

        puppet.options += " --hiera_config /dev/null"

        puppet.options += " --disable_warnings=deprecations"
    end

    config.vm.provision :shell do |shell|
        shell.path = "puppet/postprovision.sh"
        shell.args = [
            # 0 = hostname
            CONF['hosts'][0],

            # 1 = username
            CONF['admin']['user'],

            # 2 = password
            CONF['admin']['password']
        ]
    end

    synced_folders = CONF["synced_folders"].clone
    synced_folders["."] = "/vagrant"

    mount_opts = CONF['nfs'] ? [] : ["dmode=777","fmode=777"]

    synced_folders.each do |from, to|
        config.vm.synced_folder from, to, :mount_options => mount_opts, :nfs => CONF['nfs']

        if CONF['nfs'] && Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-bindfs")
            config.bindfs.bind_folder to, to
        end
    end

    # Success?
end
```

I only added the following two lines in above file:

```
config.vm.boot_timeout = 600
```

[Reference](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2973#issuecomment-35056624)

and

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2222, host_ip: "127.0.0.1", id: 'ssh'
```

[Reference](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8157#issuecomment-304487567)

What should I do?

UPDATE
I have the following settings in VirtualBox > System on Windows 8.1

**Paravitualization Interface: Default

Hardware Virtualization:

- Enable VT-x/AMD-V

- Enable Nested Paging**

And all the options above are disabled, means I cannot change anything.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: open virtualbox after you run `vagrant up` and check if the system is running slow on something

Answer (score 0):

Try and write "Vagrant ssh" after vagrant up, and if it asks for credentials it is "vagrant", if the issue is not fixed with a vagrant up --provision or a vagrant reload (halt and up), then delete your box and rebuild it from the box you started out with.

it have happen to me some times, when i try to upgrade the boxes i have, then i just have to re-setup the box and everything works.

it happens that the system does not gets the system propperly started.